# Java Eclipse JTextField not recognized right

Tags: java, swing, calculator

i am developing for a few months now and wanted to create a calculator which becomes Input from 3 JTextFields (first number; operator; second number) and gives output over an extra window. But i am receiving an issue now, and in 1 hour I couldn't get, where the issue is coming from. Because I don't know, what the issue is, i will post the whole program text below:

```
package de.programmer.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    JTextField first = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField operator = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField second = new JTextField(10);
    
    JButton button = new JButton("Calculate");
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Calculator");
    frame.setSize(800, 400);
    frame.setLocation(600, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    button.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    button.setForeground(Color.RED);
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    
    panel.add(first);
    panel.add(operator);
    panel.add(second);
    panel.add(button);
    
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            JFrame ergebnisframe = new JFrame();
            ergebnisframe.setSize(400, 200);
            ergebnisframe.setLocation(600, 300);
            ergebnisframe.setTitle("Ergebnis");
            
            JPanel ergebnispanel = new JPanel();
            ergebnispanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            
            JLabel ergebnislabel = new JLabel("Ergebnis: ");
            ergebnislabel.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
            ergebnislabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            
            String firststring = first.getText();
            int firstint = Integer.parseInt(firststring);
            String secondstring = first.getText();
            int secondint = Integer.parseInt(secondstring);
            String operatorstring = operator.getText();
            double ergebnis;
            
            if (operatorstring == "+") {
                
                ergebnis = firstint + secondint;
                String ergebnisstring=Double.toString(ergebnis);
                ergebnislabel.setText("Ergebnis: " + ergebnisstring);
                
            } 
            
            ergebnispanel.add(ergebnislabel);
            ergebnisframe.add(ergebnispanel);
            ergebnisframe.setVisible(true);
            
        }   
        
    });
    
}
```

}

When I excute and put the numbers "1" "+" and "2" in, I get this:

[image]

so i added an "else" after the if-testing with the command "ergebnislabel.setText("Etwas ist schief gelaufen!");" to get an answer where it is coming from and if I excute this, I am receiving this:

[image]

so the issue is in the if-testing. I've tested it again with the "-" as operator but received the same. I just don't know what to do. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: *"I get this:"* Post text instead of images of text. Using English for input & output would be even more useful.

Comment: 1. You should always trim() the text. 2. Use `equals()` instead of `==` when comparing strings